# need the latest version of jscrollpane.js that works with jquery version 1.7.1 or 2

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

Due to some security settings I cannot access githup. Can any body share the latest version of jscrollpane.js that works with jquery version 1.7.1 or 2.

Comment: Sorry but this simply doesn't fit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not gonna leave it up for long, as I am not trying act as a secondary host for someone else's file.. But I have been in a boat similar before so I feel your pain, so Ill make the exception despite this being counter productive to this sites true intentions, and this once I will do it.

Heres the file [download](http://rdpgroup.com/vitch-jScrollPane-2.0.0beta11-6-gf3143b0.zip)

or the full minified version from the site itself

```
/*
 * jScrollPane - v2.0.0beta12 - 2012-07-24
 * http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2010 Kelvin Luck
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 */
(function(b,a,c){b.fn.jScrollPane=function(e){function d(D,O){var ay,Q=this,Y,aj,v,al,T,Z,y,q,az,aE,au,i,I,h,j,aa,U,ap,X,t,A,aq,af,am,G,l,at,ax,x,av,aH,f,L,ai=true,P=true,aG=false,k=false,ao=D.clone(false,false).empty(),ac=b.fn.mwheelIntent?"mwheelIntent.jsp":"mousewheel.jsp";aH=D.css("paddingTop")+" "+D.css("paddingRight")+" "+D.css("paddingBottom")+" "+D.css("paddingLeft");f=(parseInt(D.css("paddingLeft"),10)||0)+(parseInt(D.css("paddingRight"),10)||0);function ar(aQ){var aL,aN,aM,aJ,aI,aP,aO=false,aK=false;ay=aQ;if(Y===c){aI=D.scrollTop();aP=D.scrollLeft();D.css({overflow:"hidden",padding:0});aj=D.innerWidth()+f;v=D.innerHeight();D.width(aj);Y=b('<div class="jspPane" />').css("padding",aH).append(D.children());al=b('<div class="jspContainer" />').css({width:aj+"px",height:v+"px"}).append(Y).appendTo(D)}else{D.css("width","");aO=ay.stickToBottom&&K();aK=ay.stickToRight&&B();aJ=D.innerWidth()+f!=aj||D.outerHeight()!=v;if(aJ){aj=D.innerWidth()+f;v=D.innerHeight();al.css({width:aj+"px",height:v+"px"})}if(!aJ&&L==T&&Y.outerHeight()==Z){D.width(aj);return}L=T;Y.css("width","");D.width(aj);al.find(">.jspVerticalBar,>.jspHorizontalBar").remove().end()}Y.css("overflow","auto");if(aQ.contentWidth){T=aQ.contentWidth}else{T=Y[0].scrollWidth}Z=Y[0].scrollHeight;Y.css("overflow","");y=T/aj;q=Z/v;az=q>1;aE=y>1;if(!(aE||az)){D.removeClass("jspScrollable");Y.css({top:0,width:al.width()-f});n();E();R();w()}else{D.addClass("jspScrollable");aL=ay.maintainPosition&&(I||aa);if(aL){aN=aC();aM=aA()}aF();z();F();if(aL){N(aK?(T-aj):aN,false);M(aO?(Z-v):aM,false)}J();ag();an();if(ay.enableKeyboardNavigation){S()}if(ay.clickOnTrack){p()}C();if(ay.hijackInternalLinks){m()}}if(ay.autoReinitialise&&!av){av=setInterval(function(){ar(ay)},ay.autoReinitialiseDelay)}else{if(!ay.autoReinitialise&&av){clearInterval(av)}}aI&&D.scrollTop(0)&&M(aI,false);aP&&D.scrollLeft(0)&&N(aP,false);D.trigger("jsp-initialised",[aE||az])}function aF(){if(az){al.append(b('<div class="jspVerticalBar" />').append(b('<div class="jspCap jspCapTop" />'),b('<div class="jspTrack" />').append(b('<div class="jspDrag" />').append(b('<div class="jspDragTop" />'),b('<div class="jspDragBottom" />'))),b('<div class="jspCap jspCapBottom" />')));U=al.find(">.jspVerticalBar");ap=U.find(">.jspTrack");au=ap.find(">.jspDrag");if(ay.showArrows){aq=b('<a class="jspArrow jspArrowUp" />').bind("mousedown.jsp",aD(0,-1)).bind("click.jsp",aB);af=b('<a class="jspArrow jspArrowDown" />').bind("mousedown.jsp",aD(0,1)).bind("click.jsp",aB);if(ay.arrowScrollOnHover){aq.bind("mouseover.jsp",aD(0,-1,aq));af.bind("mouseover.jsp",aD(0,1,af))}ak(ap,ay.verticalArrowPositions,aq,af)}t=v;al.find(">.jspVerticalBar>.jspCap:visible,>.jspVerticalBar>.jspArrow").each(function(){t-=b(this).outerHeight()});au.hover(function(){au.addClass("jspHover")},function(){au.removeClass("jspHover")}).bind("mousedown.jsp",function(aI){b("html").bind("dragstart.jsp selectstart.jsp",aB);au.addClass("jspActive");var s=aI.pageY-au.position().top;b("html").bind("mousemove.jsp",function(aJ){V(aJ.pageY-s,false)}).bind("mouseup.jsp mouseleave.jsp",aw);return false});o()}}function o(){ap.height(t+"px");I=0;X=ay.verticalGutter+ap.outerWidth();Y.width(aj-X-f);try{if(U.position().left===0){Y.css("margin-left",X+"px")}}catch(s){}}function z(){if(aE){al.append(b('<div class="jspHorizontalBar" />').append(b('<div class="jspCap jspCapLeft" />'),b('<div class="jspTrack" />').append(b('<div class="jspDrag" />').append(b('<div class="jspDragLeft" />'),b('<div class="jspDragRight" />'))),b('<div class="jspCap jspCapRight" />')));am=al.find(">.jspHorizontalBar");G=am.find(">.jspTrack");h=G.find(">.jspDrag");if(ay.showArrows){ax=b('<a class="jspArrow jspArrowLeft" />').bind("mousedown.jsp",aD(-1,0)).bind("click.jsp",aB);x=b('<a class="jspArrow jspArrowRight" />').bind("mousedown.jsp",aD(1,0)).bind("click.jsp",aB);
if(ay.arrowScrollOnHover){ax.bind("mouseover.jsp",aD(-1,0,ax));x.bind("mouseover.jsp",aD(1,0,x))}ak(G,ay.horizontalArrowPositions,ax,x)}h.hover(function(){h.addClass("jspHover")},function(){h.removeClass("jspHover")}).bind("mousedown.jsp",function(aI){b("html").bind("dragstart.jsp selectstart.jsp",aB);h.addClass("jspActive");var s=aI.pageX-h.position().left;b("html").bind("mousemove.jsp",function(aJ){W(aJ.pageX-s,false)}).bind("mouseup.jsp mouseleave.jsp",aw);return false});l=al.innerWidth();ah()}}function ah(){al.find(">.jspHorizontalBar>.jspCap:visible,>.jspHorizontalBar>.jspArrow").each(function(){l-=b(this).outerWidth()});G.width(l+"px");aa=0}function F(){if(aE&&az){var aI=G.outerHeight(),s=ap.outerWidth();t-=aI;b(am).find(">.jspCap:visible,>.jspArrow").each(function(){l+=b(this).outerWidth()});l-=s;v-=s;aj-=aI;G.parent().append(b('<div class="jspCorner" />').css("width",aI+"px"));o();ah()}if(aE){Y.width((al.outerWidth()-f)+"px")}Z=Y.outerHeight();q=Z/v;if(aE){at=Math.ceil(1/y*l);if(at>ay.horizontalDragMaxWidth){at=ay.horizontalDragMaxWidth}else{if(at<ay.horizontalDragMinWidth){at=ay.horizontalDragMinWidth}}h.width(at+"px");j=l-at;ae(aa)}if(az){A=Math.ceil(1/q*t);if(A>ay.verticalDragMaxHeight){A=ay.verticalDragMaxHeight}else{if(A<ay.verticalDragMinHeight){A=ay.verticalDragMinHeight}}au.height(A+"px");i=t-A;ad(I)}}function ak(aJ,aL,aI,s){var aN="before",aK="after",aM;if(aL=="os"){aL=/Mac/.test(navigator.platform)?"after":"split"}if(aL==aN){aK=aL}else{if(aL==aK){aN=aL;aM=aI;aI=s;s=aM}}aJ[aN](aI)[aK](s)}function aD(aI,s,aJ){return function(){H(aI,s,this,aJ);this.blur();return false}}function H(aL,aK,aO,aN){aO=b(aO).addClass("jspActive");var aM,aJ,aI=true,s=function(){if(aL!==0){Q.scrollByX(aL*ay.arrowButtonSpeed)}if(aK!==0){Q.scrollByY(aK*ay.arrowButtonSpeed)}aJ=setTimeout(s,aI?ay.initialDelay:ay.arrowRepeatFreq);aI=false};s();aM=aN?"mouseout.jsp":"mouseup.jsp";aN=aN||b("html");aN.bind(aM,function(){aO.removeClass("jspActive");aJ&&clearTimeout(aJ);aJ=null;aN.unbind(aM)})}function p(){w();if(az){ap.bind("mousedown.jsp",function(aN){if(aN.originalTarget===c||aN.originalTarget==aN.currentTarget){var aL=b(this),aO=aL.offset(),aM=aN.pageY-aO.top-I,aJ,aI=true,s=function(){var aR=aL.offset(),aS=aN.pageY-aR.top-A/2,aP=v*ay.scrollPagePercent,aQ=i*aP/(Z-v);if(aM<0){if(I-aQ>aS){Q.scrollByY(-aP)}else{V(aS)}}else{if(aM>0){if(I+aQ<aS){Q.scrollByY(aP)}else{V(aS)}}else{aK();return}}aJ=setTimeout(s,aI?ay.initialDelay:ay.trackClickRepeatFreq);aI=false},aK=function(){aJ&&clearTimeout(aJ);aJ=null;b(document).unbind("mouseup.jsp",aK)};s();b(document).bind("mouseup.jsp",aK);return false}})}if(aE){G.bind("mousedown.jsp",function(aN){if(aN.originalTarget===c||aN.originalTarget==aN.currentTarget){var aL=b(this),aO=aL.offset(),aM=aN.pageX-aO.left-aa,aJ,aI=true,s=function(){var aR=aL.offset(),aS=aN.pageX-aR.left-at/2,aP=aj*ay.scrollPagePercent,aQ=j*aP/(T-aj);if(aM<0){if(aa-aQ>aS){Q.scrollByX(-aP)}else{W(aS)}}else{if(aM>0){if(aa+aQ<aS){Q.scrollByX(aP)}else{W(aS)}}else{aK();return}}aJ=setTimeout(s,aI?ay.initialDelay:ay.trackClickRepeatFreq);aI=false},aK=function(){aJ&&clearTimeout(aJ);aJ=null;b(document).unbind("mouseup.jsp",aK)};s();b(document).bind("mouseup.jsp",aK);return false}})}}function w(){if(G){G.unbind("mousedown.jsp")}if(ap){ap.unbind("mousedown.jsp")}}function aw(){b("html").unbind("dragstart.jsp selectstart.jsp mousemove.jsp mouseup.jsp mouseleave.jsp");if(au){au.removeClass("jspActive")}if(h){h.removeClass("jspActive")}}function V(s,aI){if(!az){return}if(s<0){s=0}else{if(s>i){s=i}}if(aI===c){aI=ay.animateScroll}if(aI){Q.animate(au,"top",s,ad)}else{au.css("top",s);ad(s)}}function ad(aI){if(aI===c){aI=au.position().top}al.scrollTop(0);I=aI;var aL=I===0,aJ=I==i,aK=aI/i,s=-aK*(Z-v);if(ai!=aL||aG!=aJ){ai=aL;aG=aJ;D.trigger("jsp-arrow-change",[ai,aG,P,k])}u(aL,aJ);Y.css("top",s);D.trigger("jsp-scroll-y",[-s,aL,aJ]).trigger("scroll")}function W(aI,s){if(!aE){return}if(aI<0){aI=0}else{if(aI>j){aI=j}}if(s===c){s=ay.animateScroll}if(s){Q.animate(h,"left",aI,ae)
}else{h.css("left",aI);ae(aI)}}function ae(aI){if(aI===c){aI=h.position().left}al.scrollTop(0);aa=aI;var aL=aa===0,aK=aa==j,aJ=aI/j,s=-aJ*(T-aj);if(P!=aL||k!=aK){P=aL;k=aK;D.trigger("jsp-arrow-change",[ai,aG,P,k])}r(aL,aK);Y.css("left",s);D.trigger("jsp-scroll-x",[-s,aL,aK]).trigger("scroll")}function u(aI,s){if(ay.showArrows){aq[aI?"addClass":"removeClass"]("jspDisabled");af[s?"addClass":"removeClass"]("jspDisabled")}}function r(aI,s){if(ay.showArrows){ax[aI?"addClass":"removeClass"]("jspDisabled");x[s?"addClass":"removeClass"]("jspDisabled")}}function M(s,aI){var aJ=s/(Z-v);V(aJ*i,aI)}function N(aI,s){var aJ=aI/(T-aj);W(aJ*j,s)}function ab(aV,aQ,aJ){var aN,aK,aL,s=0,aU=0,aI,aP,aO,aS,aR,aT;try{aN=b(aV)}catch(aM){return}aK=aN.outerHeight();aL=aN.outerWidth();al.scrollTop(0);al.scrollLeft(0);while(!aN.is(".jspPane")){s+=aN.position().top;aU+=aN.position().left;aN=aN.offsetParent();if(/^body|html$/i.test(aN[0].nodeName)){return}}aI=aA();aO=aI+v;if(s<aI||aQ){aR=s-ay.verticalGutter}else{if(s+aK>aO){aR=s-v+aK+ay.verticalGutter}}if(aR){M(aR,aJ)}aP=aC();aS=aP+aj;if(aU<aP||aQ){aT=aU-ay.horizontalGutter}else{if(aU+aL>aS){aT=aU-aj+aL+ay.horizontalGutter}}if(aT){N(aT,aJ)}}function aC(){return -Y.position().left}function aA(){return -Y.position().top}function K(){var s=Z-v;return(s>20)&&(s-aA()<10)}function B(){var s=T-aj;return(s>20)&&(s-aC()<10)}function ag(){al.unbind(ac).bind(ac,function(aL,aM,aK,aI){var aJ=aa,s=I;Q.scrollBy(aK*ay.mouseWheelSpeed,-aI*ay.mouseWheelSpeed,false);return aJ==aa&&s==I})}function n(){al.unbind(ac)}function aB(){return false}function J(){Y.find(":input,a").unbind("focus.jsp").bind("focus.jsp",function(s){ab(s.target,false)})}function E(){Y.find(":input,a").unbind("focus.jsp")}function S(){var s,aI,aK=[];aE&&aK.push(am[0]);az&&aK.push(U[0]);Y.focus(function(){D.focus()});D.attr("tabindex",0).unbind("keydown.jsp keypress.jsp").bind("keydown.jsp",function(aN){if(aN.target!==this&&!(aK.length&&b(aN.target).closest(aK).length)){return}var aM=aa,aL=I;switch(aN.keyCode){case 40:case 38:case 34:case 32:case 33:case 39:case 37:s=aN.keyCode;aJ();break;case 35:M(Z-v);s=null;break;case 36:M(0);s=null;break}aI=aN.keyCode==s&&aM!=aa||aL!=I;return !aI}).bind("keypress.jsp",function(aL){if(aL.keyCode==s){aJ()}return !aI});if(ay.hideFocus){D.css("outline","none");if("hideFocus" in al[0]){D.attr("hideFocus",true)}}else{D.css("outline","");if("hideFocus" in al[0]){D.attr("hideFocus",false)}}function aJ(){var aM=aa,aL=I;switch(s){case 40:Q.scrollByY(ay.keyboardSpeed,false);break;case 38:Q.scrollByY(-ay.keyboardSpeed,false);break;case 34:case 32:Q.scrollByY(v*ay.scrollPagePercent,false);break;case 33:Q.scrollByY(-v*ay.scrollPagePercent,false);break;case 39:Q.scrollByX(ay.keyboardSpeed,false);break;case 37:Q.scrollByX(-ay.keyboardSpeed,false);break}aI=aM!=aa||aL!=I;return aI}}function R(){D.attr("tabindex","-1").removeAttr("tabindex").unbind("keydown.jsp keypress.jsp")}function C(){if(location.hash&&location.hash.length>1){var aK,aI,aJ=escape(location.hash.substr(1));try{aK=b("#"+aJ+', a[name="'+aJ+'"]')}catch(s){return}if(aK.length&&Y.find(aJ)){if(al.scrollTop()===0){aI=setInterval(function(){if(al.scrollTop()>0){ab(aK,true);b(document).scrollTop(al.position().top);clearInterval(aI)}},50)}else{ab(aK,true);b(document).scrollTop(al.position().top)}}}}function m(){if(b(document.body).data("jspHijack")){return}b(document.body).data("jspHijack",true);b(document.body).delegate("a[href*=#]","click",function(s){var aI=this.href.substr(0,this.href.indexOf("#")),aK=location.href,aO,aP,aJ,aM,aL,aN;if(location.href.indexOf("#")!==-1){aK=location.href.substr(0,location.href.indexOf("#"))}if(aI!==aK){return}aO=escape(this.href.substr(this.href.indexOf("#")+1));aP;try{aP=b("#"+aO+', a[name="'+aO+'"]')}catch(aQ){return}if(!aP.length){return}aJ=aP.closest(".jspScrollable");aM=aJ.data("jsp");aM.scrollToElement(aP,true);if(aJ[0].scrollIntoView){aL=b(a).scrollTop();aN=aP.offset().top;if(aN<aL||aN>aL+b(a).height()){aJ[0].scrollIntoView()}}s.preventDefault()
})}function an(){var aJ,aI,aL,aK,aM,s=false;al.unbind("touchstart.jsp touchmove.jsp touchend.jsp click.jsp-touchclick").bind("touchstart.jsp",function(aN){var aO=aN.originalEvent.touches[0];aJ=aC();aI=aA();aL=aO.pageX;aK=aO.pageY;aM=false;s=true}).bind("touchmove.jsp",function(aQ){if(!s){return}var aP=aQ.originalEvent.touches[0],aO=aa,aN=I;Q.scrollTo(aJ+aL-aP.pageX,aI+aK-aP.pageY);aM=aM||Math.abs(aL-aP.pageX)>5||Math.abs(aK-aP.pageY)>5;return aO==aa&&aN==I}).bind("touchend.jsp",function(aN){s=false}).bind("click.jsp-touchclick",function(aN){if(aM){aM=false;return false}})}function g(){var s=aA(),aI=aC();D.removeClass("jspScrollable").unbind(".jsp");D.replaceWith(ao.append(Y.children()));ao.scrollTop(s);ao.scrollLeft(aI);if(av){clearInterval(av)}}b.extend(Q,{reinitialise:function(aI){aI=b.extend({},ay,aI);ar(aI)},scrollToElement:function(aJ,aI,s){ab(aJ,aI,s)},scrollTo:function(aJ,s,aI){N(aJ,aI);M(s,aI)},scrollToX:function(aI,s){N(aI,s)},scrollToY:function(s,aI){M(s,aI)},scrollToPercentX:function(aI,s){N(aI*(T-aj),s)},scrollToPercentY:function(aI,s){M(aI*(Z-v),s)},scrollBy:function(aI,s,aJ){Q.scrollByX(aI,aJ);Q.scrollByY(s,aJ)},scrollByX:function(s,aJ){var aI=aC()+Math[s<0?"floor":"ceil"](s),aK=aI/(T-aj);W(aK*j,aJ)},scrollByY:function(s,aJ){var aI=aA()+Math[s<0?"floor":"ceil"](s),aK=aI/(Z-v);V(aK*i,aJ)},positionDragX:function(s,aI){W(s,aI)},positionDragY:function(aI,s){V(aI,s)},animate:function(aI,aL,s,aK){var aJ={};aJ[aL]=s;aI.animate(aJ,{duration:ay.animateDuration,easing:ay.animateEase,queue:false,step:aK})},getContentPositionX:function(){return aC()},getContentPositionY:function(){return aA()},getContentWidth:function(){return T},getContentHeight:function(){return Z},getPercentScrolledX:function(){return aC()/(T-aj)},getPercentScrolledY:function(){return aA()/(Z-v)},getIsScrollableH:function(){return aE},getIsScrollableV:function(){return az},getContentPane:function(){return Y},scrollToBottom:function(s){V(i,s)},hijackInternalLinks:b.noop,destroy:function(){g()}});ar(O)}e=b.extend({},b.fn.jScrollPane.defaults,e);b.each(["mouseWheelSpeed","arrowButtonSpeed","trackClickSpeed","keyboardSpeed"],function(){e[this]=e[this]||e.speed});return this.each(function(){var f=b(this),g=f.data("jsp");if(g){g.reinitialise(e)}else{b("script",f).filter('[type="text/javascript"],not([type])').remove();g=new d(f,e);f.data("jsp",g)}})};b.fn.jScrollPane.defaults={showArrows:false,maintainPosition:true,stickToBottom:false,stickToRight:false,clickOnTrack:true,autoReinitialise:false,autoReinitialiseDelay:500,verticalDragMinHeight:0,verticalDragMaxHeight:99999,horizontalDragMinWidth:0,horizontalDragMaxWidth:99999,contentWidth:c,animateScroll:false,animateDuration:300,animateEase:"linear",hijackInternalLinks:false,verticalGutter:4,horizontalGutter:4,mouseWheelSpeed:0,arrowButtonSpeed:0,arrowRepeatFreq:50,arrowScrollOnHover:false,trackClickSpeed:0,trackClickRepeatFreq:70,verticalArrowPositions:"split",horizontalArrowPositions:"split",enableKeyboardNavigation:true,hideFocus:false,keyboardSpeed:0,initialDelay:300,speed:30,scrollPagePercent:0.8}})(jQuery,this);
```

Comment: no problem, been there, know how it is, sitting behind a VPN or something and unable to get something you need

Comment: what version of jquery and jscrollpane did you work with. I am trying to use 1.7.1 or .2 with your version you've sent me, no luck. Not working.